# Blend for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 - License Trouble

Tags: licensing, expression-blend, visual-studio-2013, blend, activation

I just installed Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate which includes Blend.
Visual Studio installed correctly and shows up as being properly licensed. However, the help-about page in Blend is telling me that **my license expires in 30 days**! The license number listed appears to be gibberish (it includes two question marks, a total of 35 zeros, and is not hyphenated).

- Shouldn't the license number for Blend be the same as for VS?
- Does this have something to do with a "windows store apps" developer license?

There is no option to activate from the New project screen or from the help menu.

## How do I activate this version of Blend?

The help is not helpful and searching for info on "Blend for Visual Studio 2013" is not getting me anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After installation, Visual Studio 2013 is in trial mode for 30 days. You have to start it, click on "HELP" in the main menu, then on "Register Product". There (hidden behind a blue link) you have the opportunity to enter your product key. Applying the Visual Studio product key seems to also activate Blend as it now says "License expires in 0 days" in the about box.

Comment: Confirmed. I did not think to register VS because it was not apparent it was in a trial mode; a license number was already listed for each product in the VS about screen. After taking your suggestion the Blend about box says "License expires in 0 days" and the gibberish key is still gibberish, but the first character has changed from 'T' to 'M'. Thanks!

Comment: Somehow my Blend started complaining about being expired after trying to re-activate Windows 8.1 This suggestion worked - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the problem you must **install Visual Studio 2013 Update 1**.
After that the patch were installed you will see that the licence will be ok.

Comment: I've been happily coding since late Nov. of last year and didn't even realize [an update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2911573#fixedissues) was released in January! Since I got it working by following alexfr's advice I won't be able to confirm or deny the validity of this answer.

Comment: As you can see from **http://www.microsoft.com/it-it/download/details.aspx?id=41650** it's available from 17/01/2014

Comment: I got it and it installed successfully, thanks. As I previously resolved the license issue, I can't say if this would help others (is my point). [English version available here.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41650)